# tengo un problema con ajax, no se conecta con el archivo que especifico

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un archivo ***index.php*** que me identifica una variable por `get` y con esa variable busca el archivo correspondiente ***/index.php?i=login***

El index está en el directorio principal y los archivos de las páginas están en la carpeta ***pages/....php***

Este achivo contiene lo siguiente:

```
function msg_info($status, $msg) {

 $stored = array("status" => $status, "msg" => $msg);

 echo json_encode($stored);exit();
}


if($_POST['a']=='submit'){

    msg_info(0,'probando');

}

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/l2blockit.js"></script>

//fin php y comienza html y javascritp


    function login(id){

            httplocal = location.href;

            $.ajax({ data: $("#"+id).serialize(), type: 'POST', url: httplocal, dataType:"json",

                error: function(){

                    $("#msg").l2error("Error in connection to the server");

                },success: function(data){

                    if(data.status == 0){

                        $("#msg").l2error(data.msg);

                    }

                }

            });

        return false;

    }

//html

    <form method="POST" id="loginform" onsubmit="return login(this.id);" class="formulario">

            <input type="hidden" name="a" value="submit"/>

            <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="username" />

            <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="password" />

            <input type="submit" class="formulario__submit" value="Login"/>


            <div id='msg'>

        </div>

    </form>
```

No me da ninguna respuesta y tampoco me da error en el archivo log de php, estoy trabajando localmente.

Espero sus opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Hola probe el codigo y me daba error en esta parte " $("#msg").l2error(data.msg);" ,prueba poner un isset para validar la variable que recibis por post ,

te dejo el codigo que use para probar si de algo te sirve ,saludos y suerte!.

```
<?php

function msg_info($status, $msg) {

 $stored = array("status" => $status, "msg" => $msg);

 echo json_encode($stored);exit();
}


if(isset($_POST["a"]) && $_POST['a']=='submit'){

    msg_info(0,'probando');

}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function login(id){

            httplocal = location.href;

            $.ajax({ data: $("#"+id).serialize(), type: 'POST', url: httplocal, dataType:"json",

                error: function(){

                    $("#msg").l2error("Error in connection to the server");

                },success: function(data){

                    if(data.status == 0){

                        $("#msg").html(data.msg);

                    }

                }

            });

        return false;

    }


</script>


    <form method="POST" id="loginform" onsubmit="return login(this.id);" class="formulario">

            <input type="hidden" name="a" value="submit"/>

            <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="username" />

            <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="password" />

            <input type="submit" class="formulario__submit" value="Login"/>


            <div id='msg'>

        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: le cambie esto :" $("#msg").l2error(data.msg); " ,por esto :" $("#msg").html(data.msg);" ,para probar si existía algún error mas,saludos.

Comment: hola andres l2error(data.msg); en un archivo javascript que hace los efectos de loader, bloque el formulario mientras ajax hace su trabajo.

Comment: probe todo mi contenido sin el archivo index.php osea me refiero que en vez de colocar index.php?i=login ejecute todo mi codigo desde pages/login.php y me funciona perfectamente la verdad que no tengo idea de por que no me funciona de esta forma index.php?i=login

Comment: mi archivo index es el siguiente <?php
session_start();

if ($_GET['i']) {
 $controller = strtolower(htmlentities($_GET['i'])) . ".php";

 if (!file_exists("pages/". $controller)) {
  $controller = "home.php";
 }
}else{
 $controller = "home.php";
}

include "pages/". $controller;
exit();
?>